# AchievementsClient doesn't show unlock popup

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have the following code in my **BaseActivity** onCreate()

```
// Google Play Services
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, new GoogleSignInOptions
                .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                .build());
```

Then I call this **in subclass**

```
startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

I use the following code to unlock an achievement

```
 GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(activity);

        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            Games.getAchievementsClient(activity, googleSignInAccount)
                    .unlockImmediate(id);
        }
```

It works but I can't see any "Achievement has been unlocked" popups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code solved my problem

```
  Games.getGamesClient(activity, googleSignInAccount).setViewForPopups(popupView);
```